Unknown query named "fetchEstimateTemplate" requested in refetchQueries options.include array
I have the following defined function below:
const handleSave = useCallback(
   async ({
         id,
         ...values
      }: EstimateTemplateFormState) => {

         if (id && props.estimateTemplateId) {

            # # # # # # # # # Updating # # # # # # # # # # #

            const params = {
               estimateTemplateId: id,
               ...values
            };

            const {
               data
            } = await updateEstimateTemplate({
               variables: {
                  params
               },
               refetchQueries: ['fetchEstimateTemplate']
            });

         } else {

            # # # # # # # # # Creating # # # # # # # # # # #

            const params = values;

            const {
               data
            } = await createEstimateTemplate({
               variables: {
                  params
               },
               refetchQueries: ['fetchEstimateTemplate']
            });

         }
      },
      [createEstimateTemplate, updateEstimateTemplate, props.estimateTemplateId]
);

This function is used with formik to implement an autosave feature for an entity called an estimate template. When I am editing one such entity, the updating portion of the code is working perfectly from start to finish as intended. However, when I begin to create an entity I run into this issue:
Unknown query named "fetchEstimateTemplate" requested in refetchQueries options.include array

I don't quite understand why this is though. If I had to guess, it must be because editing an estimate template entity exists and in the creation process it does not. Is there a way I can fix that? I'm not too familiar with React/graphql/apollo but I'm assuming I'm missing something simple in order to fetch the newly created estimate template entity.
EDIT
My graphql function defined below:
query fetchEstimateTemplate($id: ID!) {
  estimateTemplate(id: $id) {
      .........fields........
  }
}


From the documentation:

Each element in the refetchQueries array is one of the following:

A DocumentNode object parsed with the gql function
The name of a query you've previously executed, as a string (e.g., GetComments)

To refer to queries by name, make sure each of your app's queries have a unique name.




For the GraphQL query fetchEstimateTemplate, how is that query named when you called it the first time? There is a difference between the name of the query and the name of the operation that actually gets executed. Apollo expects the name of the query as it was defined in a .graphql file or tagged by gql-tag.
For example, if your query looks like this:
query GetEstimateTemplate($id: String!) {
  fetchEstimateTemplate(id: $id) {
    __typename
    id
  }
}

You would pass in GetEstimateTemplate into refetchQueries, and not fetchEstimateTemplate. I'm not sure if I'm using the right terminology for the nae of the operation versus the name of the query, but the most important thing here is to pass in query OPERATION_NAME_HERE the OPERATION_NAME_HERE part, and not the actual query that gets called on your backend.

Thanks for replying, I should have the function defined properly so I'm not sure why it fails to get recognized. As I mentioned it works for the update action just not for the create action.

@DanRubio Have you tried passing in the exact GraphQL tagged query to see if that also works (instead of just the name of the operation)?

I ran into this problem multiple times. There are two concepts you should consider when using refetchQueries:

The query in the refetchQueries array has to be one YOU named it. In your example would be fetchEstimateTemplate (and you should name you queries with uppercase first)
Apollo calls the refetch from the queries stored in its cache. This means Apollo will grab the query along with its variables from its cache, so the query has to be called at some point before refetching it.

If you call a refetch on a query that hasn't been called before, Apollo will fail because it doesn't know what that is.
Hope this helps.
